# Docker: Reading files from inside the container without entering it

Tags: docker

I am currently using the

`sudo docker exec -it <container_name>  /bin/bash`

command to enter the container and then

`cat <my_file_path>`

to display the contents of the file. What one command should I use to display the contents of a file in a container without enter on it?
Edit:

`sudo docker exec <container_name> cat <my_file_path>`

work correct, but remember to use absolute path, because ~/ not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
sudo docker exec <container_name> cat <my_file_path>
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried to access the same pod using Lens, and it gave me below command line to access the POD:

kubectl exec -i -t -n NAME_SPACE POD_NAME -c TAG -- sh -c "clear; (bash || ash || sh)"

Comment: Hi, why Kubernetes? The question is already answered with `docker`